# Не работает copyToClipboard js в chrome extension

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Создаю расширение для `chrome`.
Столкнулся с проблемой копирования текста на js.
Сам код копирования простой.

Суть проблемы в том что код не копируется в буфер обмена.

Кто то может помочь решить проблему?

Вот сам код.

```
function copyToClipboard() {
  /* Get the text field */
  var copyText = document.getElementById("clipboard-text");

  /* Select the text field */
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /*For mobile devices*/

  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  document.execCommand("copy");

  /* Alert the copied text */
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}

document.getElementById('clipboard-copy').addEventListener("click", copyToClipboard);
```

После клика на кнопку `Copy` срабатывает событие но текст все ровно не копируется в буфер обмена.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Странно, у меня работает как в браузере так и в расширении без всяких дополнительных разрешений - причем как `execCommand`, так и `clipboard.writeText`

Версия Chrome 77.0.3865.120 (Официальная сборка), (64 бит)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В том числе, код работает и здесь

```js
// lib.js
function isInt(v) {
    return typeof v === 'number' && isFinite(v) && Math.floor(v) === v
}

function randomMinMax(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (++max - min)) + min;
}

function isProperty(prop, obj, type) {
    return typeof obj === 'object' && prop in obj && (type ? typeof obj[prop] === type : true)
}

// charGenerator.js
function charGenerator(...arrs) {
    let arr = []

    const testpush = (s) => {
        if (arr.indexOf(s) === -1) {
            arr.push(s)
        }
    }

    const set = (s, e) => {
        if (!isInt(s) || !isInt(e)) {
            return
        }
        for (let i = s; i <= e; ++i) {
            testpush(String.fromCharCode(i))
        }
    }

    let s
    for (let i = 0; i < arrs.length; ++i) {
        s = arrs[i]
        if (typeof s !== 'string' || !s.length) {
            continue
        }
        testpush(arrs[i][0])
        if (s.length > 1) {
            set(s.charCodeAt(0) + 1, s.charCodeAt(1))
        }
    }

    return arr
}

// Log.js
class Log {
    constructor(elout) {
        this.out = elout
    }
    log(mess, cl = 'log') {
        let l = document.createElement('code')
        l.className = cl
        l.textContent = mess
        this.out.appendChild(l)
    }
}

// InputRandomText.js
const numberChar = 8
const abc = charGenerator('09', 'AZ', 'az')

class InputRandomText {

    constructor(random, input) {
        this.input = input
        this.buttonExec = random
        this.buttonExec.addEventListener('click', () => {
            this.setInput()
        })
    }

    static generate(length = numberChar) {
        let l = length > abc.length ? abc.length : length
        let arr = abc.slice()
        let arrTo = []
        let i
        while (l--) {
            i = randomMinMax(0, arr.length)
            arrTo.push(arr.splice(i, 1)[0])
        }
        return arrTo.join('')
    }

    setInput() {
        this.input.value = InputRandomText.generate(randomMinMax(5, numberChar))
    }
}

// CopyToClipboard.js
class CopyToClipboard extends Log {
    constructor(input, exec, log, methodExecCommand) {
        super(log)
        this.input = input
        this.buttonExec = exec
        this.methodExecCommand = methodExecCommand
        this.write = null
        // test
        if (this.test()) {
            this.buttonExec.addEventListener('click', () => {
                this.copy()
            })
        }
        else {
            this.log('Возможно браузер не поддерживает копирование в буфер обмена', 'error')
        }
    }

    copy() {
        if (/^\s+|\s+$/g.test(this.input.value)) {
            this.input.value = this.input.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')
        }
        if (this.input.value.length) {
            this.input.select()
            try {
                this.write()
            } catch (e) {
                this.log(e.message, 'error')
                return
            }
            this.log(`Текст value.length: ${this.input.value.length} скопирован в буфер обмена`)
            return
        }
        this.log('Отсутствует текст в поле ввода', 'warn')
    }

    testExecCommand() {
        if (isProperty('queryCommandSupported', document, 'function') && document.queryCommandSupported('copy') && isProperty('execCommand', document, 'function')) {
            this.write = () => {
                document.execCommand('copy')
            }
            this.log('Копируем через document.execCommand')
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    testClipboard() {
        if (isProperty('clipboard', navigator) && isProperty('writeText', navigator.clipboard, 'function')) {
            this.write = () => {
                navigator.clipboard.writeText(this.input.value)
            }
            this.log('Копируем через navigator.clipboard')
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    test() {
        // для теста меняем порядок проверки
        // clipboard.html
        // clipboard.html?execCommand -> methodExecCommand
        if (this.methodExecCommand && this.testExecCommand()) {
            return true
        }
        if (this.testClipboard() || this.testExecCommand()) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}

// clipboard.js

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    new CopyToClipboard(
        document.body.querySelector('[data-input]'),
        document.body.querySelector('[data-exec]'),
        document.body.querySelector('[data-log]'),
        /execCommand/i.test(document.location.search)
    )
    new InputRandomText(
        document.body.querySelector('[data-random]'),
        document.body.querySelector('[data-input]')
    )
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./icons/chemistry.png" type="image/png">
    <title>clipboard</title>
    <script src="./clipboard.js" type="module"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
        }

        [data-log] {
            margin-top: 1em;
            width: 500px;
            min-height: 100px;
            padding: 1em;
            background-color: #ececec;
            border: 1px solid #9E9E9E;
        }

        [data-log]>code {
            display: block;
            margin-top: 1em;
            border-left: 3px solid green;
            padding-left: 1em;
            font-size: 1.5em;
        }

        [data-log]>code.error {
            border-left-color: red;
        }

        [data-log]>code.warn {
            border-left-color: #ff9800;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Test Clipboard</h1>
    <!-- Только для расширения и браузера
    <div>Для теста меняем порядок проверки и использования доступных API</div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="./clipboard.html?clipboard">clipboard.html?clipboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="./clipboard.html?execCommand">clipboard.html?execCommand</a></li>
    </ul>
    -->

    <button data-random>Для ленивых</button>
    <input data-input type="text" placeholder="input text">
    <button data-exec>Copy</button>
    <br><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="проверим ctrl+p"> Сюда просто вставляем что скопировано горячими клавишами [ctrl+p]
    <div data-log></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Копия манифеста

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "TestClipboard",
    "description": "TestClipboard",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "author": "Alexander Lonberg",
    "icons": {
        "32": "icons/chemistry.png"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "32": "icons/chemistry.png"
        },
        "default_popup": "clipboard.html",
        "default_title": "TestClipboard"
    },
    "permissions": []
}
```

Можете попробовать подключить эту папку как расширение или запустить в браузере
https://yadi.sk/d/055Y4jgQCTuJWQ

**UPD**
опечатка `ctrl+p`
конечно `ctrl+v`

Answer (score 1):

Убедитесь что у вас запрошено разрешение на `"clipboardWrite"` в разрешениях:

**manifest.json**:

```
{
    ...
    "permissions": [
        ...
        "clipboardWrite"
    ]
    ...
}
```

При беглом взгляде код выглядет корректно. 
В своем расширении я применяю достаточно схожий сниппет:

```js
const tempEl = document.createElement('textarea');
document.body.appendChild(tempEl);
tempEl.value = textToCopy;
tempEl.select();
const copied = document.execCommand('copy');
document.body.removeChild(tempEl);
```

Comment: У меня там есть это в `json` но все ровно не копирует. посмотрите код в вопросе. может что то упустил?

Answer (score 1):

Предполагается использование нового [Clipboard API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/clipboardapi).
С помощью него, копирование в буфер выполняется методом `navigator.clipboard.writeText()`, который принимает аргументом строковое значение - тот текст, который нужно скопировать.
В качестве результата возвращается `Promise` - то есть, выполнение *асинхронное*... но с другой стороны, можно удобно ловить ошибки. Да и `async`+`await` никто не отменял ;)

При вызове метода из popup'а в расширении Chrome, не требуется каких-либо дополнительных разрешений.
В расширениях Firefox они так же необязательны, но есть условие что вызов метода должен выполняться в коллбэке обработчика события, инициированного пользователем (например, в обработчике клика).

Я проверял в расширении в режиме разработчика Chrome v77, все работает исправно.

---

Пример, повторяющий тестовое расширение:

```js
/* popup.js */
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const inputEl  = document.querySelector('input');
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(inputEl.value)
      .then(() => { setStatus('Скопировано!'); })
      .catch(setStatus);
  });
});

function setStatus(data) {    // эта функция только для показа результата
  const statusEl = document.querySelector('p');
  if (data instanceof Error) {
    statusEl.textContent = data.message;
    statusEl.style.color = '#e00';
  } else {
    statusEl.textContent = data;
    statusEl.style.color = '#0c0';
    setTimeout(() => setStatus(''), 2e3);
  }
}
```

```css
/* popup.html > html > head > style */
body { font-family: sans-serif; }
body > * { font-size: 1rem; }
div, p { margin: 1rem 0 0 0; padding: 0.5rem 0 0 0; border-top: 1px solid #eee; }
textarea { display: block; width: 90%; }
```

```html
<!-- popup.html > html > body -->
<input value="Lorem ipsum">
<button>Скопировать в буфер обмена</button>
<div>Сюда можно вставить текст (для проверки):</div>
<textarea></textarea>
<p></p>
```

Манифест тестового расширения:

```js
{
  "name": "Test extension",
  "description": "Test extension",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

---

При использовании на веб-странице (то есть, не в расширении), нужно учесть три момента:

- по-видимому, Clipboard API работает только если страница загружена через HTTPS
- некоторые браузеры могут требовать запрос разрешений через Permissions API
- Clipboard API экспериментальный, а значит он не поддерживается старыми/отстающими браузерами, и (на данный момент) поддержка отсутствует в Android WebView (а в Chrome для Android - она есть)

Страница на MDN: https://wiki.developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard